# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError firebase Firestore android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Could not find

```
class 'com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryListenOptions', referenced from method com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions$Builder.setQuery
07-20 18:23:10.220 10100-10100/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dpvtechnology.zemon, PID: 10100
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryListenOptions
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions$Builder.setQuery(FirestoreRecyclerOptions.java:117)
```

Comment: What do you expect exactly ?

Comment: Please add the code that produces this error.

Answer (score -1):

Did you use progaurd?
If so, these type of problems usually are caused by it. Check your progaurd roles.
you can add this rule to your proguard rules to solve the problem

```
 -keep class com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryListenOptions { *; }
```

Comment: Could you provide rules of ProGuard to fix issue? Without that your answer is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: modified and BTY I can not add comment because I am a newbie here